# Request.QueryString "Index was outside the bounds of the array."

Tags: arrays, vb.net, query-string, indexoutofboundsexception

As of now, I'm sending only an empty array through the query-string.

```
selectPONumber=[]
```

Have no idea why I'm getting this error.  The stacktrace points the Next on this.

```
If context.Request.QueryString("selectPONumber").Count <> 0 Then
    For u = 1 To request.QueryString("selectPONumber").Count
        selectPONumber.Add(request.QueryString("selectPONumber")(u))
    Next
End If
```

How is it getting past the if if the .Count is 0?  Is my query string formatting incorrect?

If it had values it would look like

```
selectPONumber=[value1, value2,...]
```

Many thanks in advance!

**Extra Credit**

Yes, vb.net did not read selectPONumber as an array when using [].  All that's necessary is to to do selectPONumber=value1, value2,...

Thank-you very much for the above and beyond!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you saying your querystring looks like this?

```
mysite/mypage.aspx?selectPONumber=[]
```

If so, you are passing the string "[]" and `Context.Request.QueryString("selectPONumber").Count == 2`. It would evaluate to 0 for `mysite/mypage.aspx?selectPONumber=`.

Also, VB.NET arrays are zero-based. Use:

```
For u = 0 To request.QueryString("selectPONumber").Count-1
```